# "No root file system is defined." error while trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu into a 3 graphic card z390 motherboard with 1 DDR4 on i7 CPU.

But I'm stuck in installation type no partitions

[image: Photo of the error]

> No root file system is defined.
>
> Please correct this from the partitioning menu.

Comment: Use default settings.

Comment: Correct: Your image shows that you did not define any partitions. Do so, or go back a screen and let the installer do it automatically.

Comment: watch some youtube tutorial bro and commecnt some useful question like me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

From your image I see an empty drive.

press + to create a partition that should/could be ext4 and mounted on / 
press + to create another one also ext4 and mounted /home (so your data is separated from system).

You can go from there...
on sizes:

> My recomnedation would be 60Gb to 120GB for /
> 120+GB for /home (depending on your plans and what you will install)